# jQuery/AJAX execution of PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery/AJAX to run a PHP file on a server. This PHP simply adds a row with some constants to a database. Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Submit Application</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    $.get("http://.../submitApp.php");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="javascript:doSomething()">
  <p>
    <label for="programName"></label>
    <input type="text" name="programName" id="programName" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="greQuant"></label>
    <input type="text" name="greQuant" id="greQuant" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="greVerbal"></label>
    <input type="text" name="greVerbal" id="greVerbal" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submitApp" id="submitApp" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon pressing the submit button on the above form, nothing seems to happen. I should mention I am running this locally via DreamWeaver. I know for a fact that the code is reaching the JavaScript method and that the PHP code is functional. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: try `onsubmit='doSomething()'` instead of `action`

Comment: Would this still help if I told you I knew for a fact that the code is getting to the JS method?

Comment: really ? or did you just add that line ? lol smh

Comment: what do you see in the XHR tab in firefox upon clicking the submit button? is there any successful XHR/Ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use POST instead of GET to do this work.

```
function doSomething() {
   var programName = $('#programName').val();
   var greQuant = $('#greQuant').val();
   var greVerbal = $('#greVerbal').val();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submitApp.php", //URL that you call
      data: { programName: programName, greQuant:greQuant, greVerbal:greVerbal } //var in post: var from js
   }).done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);//change to something to indicate action
   }
});
```

and with your php, handle like this

```
<?php

$programName = $_POST['programName'];
$greQuant = $_POST['greQuant'];
$greVerbal = $_POST['greVerbal'];

//do something important

?>
```

this is just a simple example, you need apply some security to this php code